# ncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a component in React. Rather than listing all the lines of JSX I want to render in the return() section, I sometimes have been storing the information in a variable and just calling {variable}. This has worked well for all other instances other than the one I am stuck on now. I have stripped all of the JSX away leaving an empty div as a tester, but I am still getting the same error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I would really appreciate any help! 
Thanks in advance

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Inbox.module.css';


const Cancel = (props) =>{
    let message;
    message =(<div></div>);

    return(
        {message}
    );
}

export default Cancel;
```

Comment: This isn't your actual code is it? Do you mean to return `message` not `{message}` since it's not JSX as you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here,

```
return(
    {message}
);
```

`{message}` is an object and you are trying to render object.

You have two ways to handle this,

Use [`Fragments`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
return (
  <React.Fragment> {message} </React.Fragment>
)
```

Or the short syntax is,

```
return (
  <> {message} </>
)
```

**Or** another way is,

```
return( 
   message      //without curly braces , not good idea because you may have multiple other elements 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing it the way you did it you return an object `message`, I guess you want to wrap `{message}` like this `<>{message}</>` this way you return jsx and interpolate the variable `message`

Hope this helps.